# Is there a way to dynamically change the sequenceName param in @Sequence Generator?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, annotations

I have a database with different schemas that have the same tables inside them. (I know this is not a good setup but can't change the db). So for every hibernate model I need to change the the table name in @Table and the sequence name in @SequenceGenerator to reflect the schema that's being used.

I've done it for the table section by creating a new naming strategy in the hibernate configs, but I can't find a way to do it for sequence generator.

I realize that I may be able to do this my creating a custom sequence generator that replicates what the DB does, but I want to be able to use the existing sequence in case it's altered in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Tried changing the search path instead? `SET search_path TO value`

Comment: Just got back to this project did this when defining getConnection inside the datasource and this worked. Thanks!